# Appending last JSON object to the previous in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a function that is outputting an array of json objects, where the last one is unique in structure:

```js
// multi
[
  { "min": 10, "max": 200, "sum": 580, "avg": 72.5 },
  { "min": 10, "max": 470, "sum": 8300, "avg": 103.75 },
  { "largest": 470 }
]

// single
[
  { "min": 20, "max": 190, "sum": 270, "avg": 90 },
  { "largest": 190 }
]
```

Is it possible to have it append the last part `{ "largest": n }` to the other objects in the array?

So the output would be:

```js
// multi
[ { "min": 10, "max": 200, "sum": 580, "avg": 72.5,    "largest": 470 },
  { "min": 10, "max": 470, "sum": 8300, "avg": 103.75, "largest": 470 }
]

// single
[
  { "min": 20, "max": 190, "sum": 270, "avg": 90, "largest": 190 }
]
```

[Here is a link to the snippet](https://codepen.io/markbattistella/pen/abJbyZz) of code that outputs the above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Slice the array to omit the last entry, then map each entry to merge in the last entry

```js
function mergeLastEntry(arr) {
  const last = arr[arr.length - 1] // get the last entry

  // map each object (except the last) to merge in the `last` object
  return arr.slice(0, -1).map(o => ({ ...o, ...last }))
}

const multi =[{"min":10,"max":200,"sum":580,"avg":72.5},{"min":10,"max":470,"sum":8300,"avg":103.75},{"largest":470}]
const single = [{"min":20,"max":190,"sum":270,"avg":90},{"largest":190}]

console.log("multi", mergeLastEntry(multi))
console.log("single", mergeLastEntry(single))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: thanks for that, seems its 50% of the way there (unless I've put it in the wrong spot). i've updated the Pen

Comment: @markb I've updated my answer to treat the original arrays as immutable. I've also added a runnable example